# Code Mirror merge View for JSON

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, json

I am writing a code to show the merge View for JSONs in code mirror. The problem I am facing is with the mode of code mirror. It is working fine for strings but not for JSONs. I tried using application/json but still no luck.

Below is my code:

```
$timeout(function() {
  var a = document.getElementById("diffView");
  dv = CodeMirror.MergeView(a, {
    value: json1,
    orig: json2,

    lineNumbers: true,
    //  mode: "javascript",
    mode: "application/json",

    highlightDifferences: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    autoCloseBrackets: true,
    lineWrapping: true
  });
}, 1);
```

json1 and json2 are my jsons.

Comment: JSON is string data...therefore this is confusing. What is `typeof json1`?

Comment: can you check with text/html?